# Highly concurrent application?

Tags: java

I was asked this questions in one interview.

> Suppose there is a requirement of highly concurrent application e.g. Email application like Gmail where in 
>   say there 100K users accessing the application at the same time.
>
> You are allowed to ask only 3 questions to client which 3 questions will you ask?
>
> Client in this case is company who want the application to get developed. e.g.Google [Disclaimer: Name is 
>   just to give idea. I know what you must be thinking :) ]

I was really confused there can be n number of questions starting with technology, hardware configuration etc. Can some one tell me which can be best suited questions in above case.

Comment: Well, this is broad range question and everyone will have their own view I guess. By the view who is client here? user who is accessing gmail (or) Google?

Comment: 1. Do you have a full tech spec of the product? 2. How much money will you pay? 3. Do you have cookies?

Comment: The most important question is; are they actually likely to use this site and how will the business make money or does the business have big plans that are unlikely to be realised. Note: I suspect google doesn't make a profit from running gmail alone.

Comment: Jokes aside, was that a manager level, system architect level, or just developer level question?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy :) system architect level question.

Answer (score 4):

1. SLAs (expected uptime, response times, usage patterns, etc.)
2. How much can be spent on maintenance (servers/cloud, support)
3. Expected growth

Comment: Client answers: 100% uptime, minimal response time, maximum usage. Minimal budget for support. Fully scalable to accomodate any growth.

Comment: @AlexLynch: I see your point. 100% uptime - (nearly?) impossible. Minimal support budget - customers not happy, 100% uptime even less possible. Handling *any* growth - cost of hardware grows at least linearily (if we are lucky).

Comment: Of course you are being completely realistic. An interviewer, however, might give my answers in response to your questions, i'm just trying to give readers something to think about. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Budget?
2. Desired delivery date?
3. Do you have a pen to sign or will you need one?